# Get Assimp import information uisng the callback

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, assimp

I'm using Assimp to import .fbx files to my engine. Everytime a file is imported, information about the file content is created.

I have set up a [aiLogStream](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_log_stream.html) to get the info.

```
struct aiLogStream stream;
stream = aiGetPredefinedLogStream(aiDefaultLogStream_DEBUGGER, nullptr);
aiAttachLogStream(&stream);
```

This give the info to the output window in visual studio.

The aiLogStream struct has a [aiLogStreamCallback](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/cimport_8h.html#a8fd7aab231c7632030590290ca4f57d8) to get the info but I don't know how to implement the callback.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The callback is used to pipe the incoming log messages to your application. So you have the possibility to print this message onto a special log-windows or into a special file for instance. To implement this just define a function with the defined signature of the callback like:

```
// Implementation for your own log stream callback
void myCallback( const char *msg, char *userData) {
  printToMyWindows( msg );
  printIntoMyFile( msg );
}

// Register it
struct aiLogStream stream;
stream.callback = myCallback;
aiAttachLogStream(&stream);
```

Now your own callback will be called whenever a log message will be written somewhere in the Asset-Importer-Lib.

Hope that helps. And sorry for the late response, found this question today.